# How to deal a multiple page REST reply

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services, windows-phone-7

I have a WP7 silverlight (technology may or may not be relevant) application that calls multiple (10 or more) REST web services for similar data and them puts them all together in a single collection. The data itself is not relevant to the question.

How do I deal with REST services when the reply has more than one page. What I mean is, all of these services I call reply with data, but at the top it says "Page 1 of 11". So I have to call it again and again with something like ...&page=1...&page=2... I've found that writing a custom framework for this is a pain and can be a little fragile. Basically I have a thread that goes out to all of the services initially, then finds out how many pages there are. From there I'm not sure how to proceed. I don't know the best way to spawn the threads from there.

Is there a best practice for this or maybe even a frame work I can follow?

Answer (score 1):

You should use simple requests - on wp7 they are async so you have to do something like:

1. fetch the number of pages, store it in TOTAL_NUM, set NUM = 1
2. call request to fetch data on PAGE == NUM
3. when req is back, parse it, NUM++ if NUM != TOTAL_NUM then goto pt. 2

Something like this:

```
public void FetchData(int pageNum)
{
    Uri address = ...;

    var request = WebRequest.Create(address);
    // ...  init request

    request.BeginGetRequestStream(asyncResp => {
                                                    var response = (WebResponse) request.EndGetResponse(asyncRes);
                                                    ParseAndSave(response, pageNum);
                                                    NUM++;

                                                    if (NUM != TOTAL_NUM)
                                                        FetchData(NUM);

                                                }, null);                                                               
}
```

keep in mind that I didn't compile it or anything... it may be not the best way to do it, but should work with minimum effort :)

Comment: I'll let this slide this time, but I expect you to do full unit tests and regression testing on all future code snippets. Thanks! That said, I like the idea of dumbing down the web requests to be able to simplify the code (maybe even looping requests). Right now I'm using webclient, but I think I should switch to the simpler webrequest.

Comment: I don't like WebClient... you can't do req/resp compression... for simple things it may be ok, but on the phone it's better to have as little data as possible.